# How to display a user prompt in a calculator program

Tags: calculator

I'm struggling with a while loop problem. Once the calculation is done, I want the user to be asked whether they want to close the calculator or clear the screen and retry.

How can I use the while loop to do that, if at all?

```
print ("Calculator Program")
clear="c"
while clear=="c":
    one=input("Enter your first number:")
    two=input("Enter your second number:")
    operator=input("""Choose an operator:
1) Add
2) Subtract
3) Multiply
4) Divide
""")
    if operator == '1':
         ans=float(one)+float(two)
         print (ans)
    elif operator == '2':
         ans=float(one)-float(two)
         print (ans)
    elif operator == '3':
         ans=float(one)*float(two)
         print (ans)
    elif operator == '4':
         ans=float(one)/float(two)
         print(ans)
```

Comment: Post the code in your question; don't use external hosting sites. If it's too much to post here, trim it down to only the relevant sections.

Comment: It's also helpful if you add a tag to identify the language you're using, so that people who are familiar with it notice the question.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to add code to the thread, it seemed very complicated. Do I have to just indent every line by 4 spaces?

Answer (score 0):

For the last line in your loop add:

```
clear = input("[c]lear or [e]xit")
```

If the user types anything besides "c" the loop will break and the program will finish execution

Comment: If you run it it still doesn't give the user the option, it just keeps looping. I'm not sure how to fix that

Comment: And it's indented so that it's still inside the loop?

Comment: yes, after the answer has been printed, I want the question to appear. "C" will go back to the start and "E" will finish the program

Comment: Right now your while expression is checking for the lower case "c".  You should change that to uppercase clear=="C" if you just want the uppercase to work otherwise you could do clear.lower()=="c" which will match both cases

Comment: Thanks for that tip, but the problem is the question still won't print. The four operators are just looped again and again.

Comment: And you have the line above located at the same indentation level as the last "elif"?  So that it's still included in the while loop but not included in any of the if-else logic..

Comment: Aha! That's it. Thanks a lot, I will remember this for the future

Comment: Great! Glad you got it figured out